# How to access key, value in a python dictionary? (error: "need more than 1 value to unpack")

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to do something really simple:

```
vowels = {'a':10, 'e'11, 'i':15, 'o':17, 'u':3}
```

All I want to do, is access the key and value inside of a loop.

But when using a for loop like so:

```
for vowel, count in vowels:

    print(count)
```

I get the error:

```
need more than 1 value to unpack
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: the data structure you are using is a dictionary, not a list

Comment: I changed "list" to "dictionary" in your question because you are using a dictionary.  A list would be something like `[1, 2, 3, ...]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)<sup>1</sup> method of the dictionary:

```
for vowel, count in vowels.items():

    print(count)
```

Otherwise, you will only iterate over the dictionary's keys.

---

<sup>1</sup>In Python 2.x, you should call [`dict.iteritems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) instead to avoid creating an unnecessary list.

Answer (score 0):

its dictionary you cant handle the way you are doing it

dictionary has key,value pair, follow like this

```
vowels = {'a':10, 'e'11, 'i':15, 'o':17, 'u':3}
for key in vowels.keys():
    print vowels[key]
```

some intro in dictionary
`vowels.keys()` will give you list of keys
`vowels.values()` will give you list of values
`vowels.items()` will give you (key,value) pair